# relation "(table name)" does not exist in non-public schema

Tags: postgresql

Windows, pgAdmin, PostgreSQL server hosted on Amazon AWS. Logged in on PgAdmin 4 as admin/owner, accessing an admin created database called 'client'.

I have two identical post-gis enabled tables, one tabled is named 'testboundary' and stored in the public schema, the other is named 'testboundaryNW' and is stored in a new schema called 'NW'.

When I right click the table in public and query this:

```
SELECT *
FROM testboundary
```

I get the contents of the table returned as expected.

When I right click the table in the 'NW' schema and query this:

```
SELECT *
FROM testboundaryNW
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  relation "testboundarynw" does not exist
LINE 2: FROM testboundaryNW
             ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 15
```

Why is this? Usage/access rights are the same on public and NW schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, when querying anything other than the public schema, you need to change the syntax of the query from:

```
SELECT *
FROM testboundaryNW
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM "NW"."testbonudaryNW"
```

if I renamed the table to testboundarynw (no caps on NW) I don't need the "" around it.

Comment: Or you can adjust the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That is worth an answer on its own in order to salvage this Q&A as interesting for the community. OP can then decide which answer to accept.